# I want to set variable once in an applescript droplet but it makes me set it for every file

Tags: applescript

I wrote an applescript droplet where I would like to:

1. drag one or more images onto the droplet
2. 3 display dialogs appear asking 'width', 'height', 'format'
3. process all dropped images using the above text returned of the
   3 display dialogs

Currently, the 3 display dialogs appear for each image (e.g. 3 images = 9 dialogs appear). Is there a way I can only answer these dialogs once? Here's my script:

```
on run
    display dialog "This is a droplet"
end run

on open draggedItems

set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters

--ask for new width
set newWidth to text returned of (display dialog "New Width" default answer ¬
    "45" buttons {"Continue…", "Cancel"} ¬
    default button 1)

--ask for new height
set newHeight to text returned of (display dialog "New Height" default answer ¬
    "45" buttons {"Continue…", "Cancel"} ¬
    default button 1)

--ask for formatType
set newFormat to text returned of (display dialog "Image Format" default answer ¬
    "jpg" buttons {"Continue…", "Cancel"} ¬
    default button 1)
--repeat
repeat with i in draggedItems
    set theFile to (i as alias)
    set theFilePath to (the POSIX path of theFile)
    set fullFileName to name of (info for theFile without size)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
    set fileNameNoExtension to first text item of fullFileName
    --set fileExtension to second text item of fullFileName
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid

    do shell script ("/usr/local/bin/convert " & quoted form of theFilePath & " -resize " & newWidth & "x" & newHeight & "\\! ~/desktop/" & fileNameNoExtension & "." & newFormat)
end repeat
end open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on open draggedItems` is already an repeat loop, if you drop 4 files on this droplet

```
on open draggedItems
    display dialog (draggedItems as text)
end open
```

you will get 4 different dialogs.

You could do something like this

```
property askingForNew : true

on open draggedItems
    if askingForNew is true then
        --display dialogs
        set askingForNew to false
    end if
    display dialog (draggedItems as text)
end open
```

or drag the folder on the droplet and go through the files of it ([like this](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=21039)).